# Re-sizing prestashop 1.5 shome slider

Tags: html, css, prestashop-1.5

im using Prestashop 1.5 and i want the home slider to be 600px tall and 2000px wide... So I changed those dimensions in the back-office inside the modules configuration..

The size changed but images are no longer centered, they cover the whole slider but seem to be zoomed in a way so that I cant see the image correctly..

Should I change anything else? See picture attached!
[image: slider preeview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your existing slides, then create them again, but with images that are wider than 2000px and higher than 600px.

After that, empty your PrestaShop cache.